# Package and HTML editor issue with Eclipse and Gradle

Tags: java, eclipse

I have created a gradle project in Eclipse and want to make it a web app. So I added the packages `src/main/resources` and `src/main/webapp`.
The thing now is that they wont show up in the project explorer.

My first question, how do I see my packages?

I can see the file inside the src directory, but then when I add a file index.html inside the src/main/webapp directory, it wont show up innside the editor window it starts running as a html document. How do I fix this?

Comment: sounds like you have associated html to open in an external browser, right click the file and check the open settings. You can set html to be open in an texteditor, rich text editor or browser etc. Also check the preferences to se file association for html and also check the eclipse browser settings, if it is set to open internal or external and what  browser agent is used.

Comment: Do you have Eclipse BuildShip plugin installed? Did you actually create packages or just folders? Since those directories are meant to contain resource files (not java files), there is no point in making them Java packages AFAIK. You can open the HTML file with the HTML editor (if you have it installed) with Right-click on file > Open With.

Comment: regarding seeing the packages, this depends the perspecitve, and how you set them up. What is the project type? you can create a dynamic web project for instance. Or custom the filter for the explorer, there is an icon above on the right side. Sorry for the details, but I dont have an eclipse installed at this moment at this machine.. I will switch machine soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In project explorer you might have checked empty packages.

**Check the flag and make it unchecked as shown**:
[image]

**And the open html settings**:

[image]

**See associations**:
[image]